# Align tops of two columns of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to compare two images side by side. I am trying to grab and store the heights of the first column, to apply the heights to the corresponding image in the other column.

Right now I can only get it to either get the first height or all of the height combined.

http://jsfiddle.net/F34Ex/

```
<div id="project">          

    <ul id="new">
        <li> <img src="#" />New 1 </li>
        <li> <img src="#" />New 2 </li>
        <li> <img src="#" />New 3 </li>
        <li> <img src="#" />New 4 </li>
        <li> <img src="#" />New 5 </li>
    </ul>


    <ul id="old">
        <li> <img src="#" />Old 1 </li>
        <li> <img src="#" />Old 2 </li>
        <li> <img src="#" />Old 3 </li>
        <li> <img src="#" />Old 4 </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Jquery to collect heights of ('**#new li**') and to display the height after the image in ('**#old li**'). I know that I have to change `.append()` to `.css('height', theHeight)`

```
$(function () {
    $('#new li').each(function() {
        theHeight = $(this).height();

        $('#old li').each(function() {
            $(this).append(theHeight + ' ');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Will both columns always contain the same number of images?

Comment: Yes, they will.

Are you asking, to know if the old list would ever have more images than the new list?

Comment: You could do it using table or table properties with CSS or even using  rows instead 2 lists of columns, you could do it using CSS only.
If you really want to use jQuery, refer to index(), catch the item with the same index for all items and you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(function () {
      $('#new li').each(function (idx, val) {
          theHeight = $(this).height();
          $('#old li').eq(idx).css("height", theHeight);
      });
  });
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/j85B2/)

Comment: According to your code and demo, all the heights in the old column don't match the images in the new column.

Comment: I'm changing the height of the `li` container and not the height of the `img` itself, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array here:

```
var theHeight = new Array();
var i = 0;
$('#new li').each(function() {
    theHeight[i++] = $(this).height();
}
```

then loop over it:

```
var i = 0;
$('#old li').each(function() {
     $(this).height(theHeight[i++]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#new li').each(function (i) {
        theHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
        $('#old li:eq(' + i + ') img').height(theHeight);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/F34Ex/2/)**

This code loops through each list item in the new column, takes the image height, and applies it to the corresponding image in the old column by using `.each()`'s index.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F34Ex/3/).

```
$(function () {
    $('#new li').each(function (i) {
        //i is the index number which corresponds to the second set
        $('#old li:eq('+i+')').height( $(this).height() );
    });
});
```

Combined and simplified. You got the iteration over the **#new li** right, then you just need to correspond each of those to the same index in the **#old li**.

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided are good, but this use case is basically why a `<table>` exists - to help you organize things in a grid-like fashion.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <img src="#" />New 1
        </td>
        <td>
         <img src="#" />Old 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <img src="#" />New 2
        </td>
        <td>
         <img src="#" />Old 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the text that's in the cells. So if one side has more text than the other, the images wouldn't be the same height.

Comment: What do you mean? "New 1" etc are there.

Comment: If **"New 1"** text actually read **"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."** while **"Old 1"** was unchanged, it won't account for the images that are supposed to have the same height in that row.

Comment: depends on how you arrange it. I'm guessing that for this he wouldn't expect to have a large block of text. It seems like he's literally doing "new 1" kinda thing.

Comment: I like to play it safe, and not assume that unless it's an explicit condition. Keeping in mind that the data that's been provided is probably simplified to the bare bones.